# Preload WebView in Xamarin Forms on iOS

Tags: ios, webview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a WebView in a ContentPage that I am instantiating and setting the url to the WebView in the constructor. I am then later showing this ContentPage with PushModalAsync. Thing is, the WebView doesn't seem to be attempting to load until I do the Push. Is there a way to have it preload in the background instead of waiting until it is shown?

Comment: FYI, in this particular case I'm loading an image (png) as the source of the webview, not an html page, although I would think the means of preloading would be similar.

Answer (score 2):

You can fetch content using HttpClient and then Load WebView with html data

```
WebView.Source =  new HtmlWebViewSource() { BaseUrl = urlPreloaded, Html = httpClientData}
```

In this way, the html data will be pre-loaded.

Comment: The source is actually an image, not html.  Will this work similarly?  FYI, I'm loading it into a webview instead of an Image view so that zooming is easy.

Comment: in case of image create `httpClientData` in code as html page and add image tag in that.

Comment: @jpcoder   Did this work? The answer seems good. I just want to know if this has worked for you..